# Why we need serialized Class for ID while getting object using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, serialization

Why we need serialized Class while getting object using hibernate below method

```
public abstract Object get(Class class1, Serializable serializable)
        throws HibernateException;
```

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/), Serializable object given as an second argument is identifier of entity. All identifiers do implement Serializable directly, or in case of primitive identifiers key do have Serializable wrapper class. It cannot be more specific type, because Hibernate is not aware of type of user defined class used as a composite key.